# Parsing large XML file to find data linked to another piece of data

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing

I have a 9mb xml file that contains information on the system I am writing the script for. The system saves small files called `symbols` each symbol has a `tick type` and belongs to an `estate`.

The data is stored in this format.

```
<Symbol SymbolName="name" Estate="estate" TickType="type" />
```

I currently parse the file and write 3 files, each contains a list of one of the three things.

What I need to do is somehow store the data in a list or dictionary in a way that all symbols can be written to a file and their corresponding type and estate is written to another part of the file.

The outcome is intended to be an html file that has a dropdown where you select and `estate` and it shows the `symbols` in it and gives the `type` of each `symbol`.

My current method of parsing is using the `xml.dom.minidom` module and then using `getElementsByTagName` this does return 3 lists of each of the things I want but doesn't link them to their corresponding members of other lists.

Answer (score 0):

Install the follwing libs

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install flask
```

and then run the follow piece og code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

xml = '''\
<Symbol SymbolName="A" Estate="e1" TickType="t1" />
<Symbol SymbolName="B" Estate="e1" TickType="t2" />
<Symbol SymbolName="C" Estate="e1" TickType="t2" />
<Symbol SymbolName="D" Estate="e2" TickType="t2" />
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
symbols = soup.find_all('symbol')
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def filter_symbols():
    constraint = request.args.get('estate', None)
    estate_in_req = 'estate' in request.args

    return jsonify(symbols=[
        {'name': s.get('symbolname'), 'type': s.get('ticktype')}
        for s in symbols if not estate_in_req or s.get('estate') == constraint
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now you have a webserver that solves your problem.

localhost:5000/?estate=e1

will output:

```
{
  "symbols": [
    {
      "name": "A", 
      "type": "t1"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "B", 
      "type": "t2"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "C", 
      "type": "t2"
    }
  ]
}
```

to your browser.

I hope you can use the code snippet go work forward with your solution.

If you have performence issues use a database. ;)

--
brunsgaard

Comment: this looks like a beautiful solution. However there is a slight problem. I am doing this on a computer owned and maintained by my work place. It is pretty locked down with proxys firewalls and all sorts of anti-virus, therefore pip and easy_install don't work (it won't let powershell connect to internet locations). It is also a windows machine and bs4 is only supplied as a tar.gz file, and I have no way of extracting it on this pc. @brunsgaard